# Is parsing a variety of file types feasible in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parsing, character-encoding

I'm writing a script that searches various file locations, and stores the file path and a copy to a SharePoint site if it matches certain user inputs.

These inputs include: filename, file type, and date created.

As per my question, I'm trying to include a parameter that narrows down files by parsing file contents but I seem to have hit a wall.

This is what I have so far for parsing a file:

`$local_files` stores the return of `Get-ChildItem` (`gci` uses type/name/date as parameters).

`$search_parameters[3]` would be equivalent to:

```
$Content -like "*test*" -or $Content -like "*help*" # user input put into wildcard
```

```
foreach ($Location in $local_files) {
    $Content = Get-Content -Path $Location.FullName -Raw

    if (Invoke-Expression $search_parameters[3]) {
        Write-Host -Object ('File ({0}) matched file content search terms' -f $Location.FullName)
        #Leave location in array
    } else {
        #if content not in file
        #remove that location from the array
        $local_files = $local_files | ? {$_.FullName -ne "$Location"}
        Write-Host -Object ('File ({0}) did not match file content search terms - removed' -f $Location.FullName)
    }
```

This seems to work for .txt files, but as soon as it comes across anything other than a .txt file it...doesn't.

Example:

This is the result of a .txt file:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Sgouldin\Desktop\PPB\Scripts\General + Test>> $Content
SharePoint
```

This is the result of a .docx file:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Sgouldin\Desktop\PPB\Scripts\General + Test>> $Content
Oœ£œƒXø
```

I've done some research as to what was causing this issue, and from my understanding it's due to a different encoding with .docx vs .txt. Another post's answer had someone saying that a .docx is a hidden zip file, and unzipping gives you a list of XML files (UTF8 encoding).

I've tried adding an encoding parameter to my `Get-Content` call with no success

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path $Location.FullName -Encoding "UTF8" -Raw
```

I did however find a method that would allow me to parse .docx files:

```
#Instance of word
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $false

#take list of .docx
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -File -Filter "*.docx" | %{
    $Filename = $_.FullName

    #open file and take content of word file
    $Document = $Word.Documents.Open($Filename, $false, $true)
    $range = $document.Content

    #if content have your word, print path of word file
    if ($range.Text -like "*tot*") {
        $Filename
    }

    $word.Documents.Close($false)
}
```

Going back to my question: Is there a reliable/reasonable way that I can search the contents of different types of files?

I can put the above method into use and that would take care of .docx files, however it's an extra step and there's an unknown number of .docx files, let alone an unknown number of files with extensions other than .docx and .txt.

Comment: What is `$search_parameters[3]`? Please see [this help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, will clarify variables.

Comment: nope ... the structure of files makes it not possible. you need to have the code to parse each file type _other than text_ since only text is built into PoSh. you are likely going to need to filter your files types by known extensions and handle them in groups that use the same parser.